# Protobuf use repeated oneof message vs many empty fields

Tags: protocol-buffers, anyof

I'm designing a protobuf to represent an event, where each event can hold extra fields.
There are a lot of possible extra fields (~100), but only a small portion of them will be used in each message (~3)

Each extra field will be used only once, but multiple of them can exist, therefore I would like to have a concept of an `anyof` message type, but unfortunately, there is no such thing in protobuf.

So to try and mock this behavior, and as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2592) discussion I thought I can put all my extra fields in a `oneof`, wrap it with a message, and use this message as `repeated` in my event:

```proto
message ExtraField {
  oneof extra_field_value {
    string extraData1 = 1;
    uint64 extraData2 = 2;
    ....
    SomeOtherMessage extraData100 = 100;
  }
}

message MyEvent {
  uint64 timestamp = 1;
  string event_name = 2;
  string some_other_data = 3;
  ...
  repeated ExtraField extra_fields = 8;
}
```

Even though this solution is more explicit for my understanding, it isn't the most memory effective, and the repeated message with `oneof` implementation allows to add the same extra field more than once (unwanted behavior)

I can also just write all the extra fields as-is in an inner message, but most of them will be empty all the time

```proto
message ExtraFields {
  string extraData1 = 1;
  uint64 extraData2 = 2;
  ....
  SomeOtherMessage extraData100 = 100;
}

message MyEvent {
  uint64 timestamp = 1;
  string event_name = 2;
  string some_other_data = 3;
  ...
  extraFields extra_fields = 8;
}
```

If I understand correctly, using empty fields in a message isn't going to make my serialized data larger, and therefore the second protobuf design is the preferred practice

Am I correct?
Is there another protobuf design for my needs?